# How to modify properties of winforms objects at runtime? (C++/CLI)

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

**Hypothetical:**

There is a text box with the default value of "test" (`this->textBox1->Text = L"test";`) and, at runtime, the value of the text property is set to "modified" by a statement in main().

**The cold, hard truth:**

This doesn't seem to be possible because the object is `private`. Also there is a comment in the form header that says it's a dumb idea to modify things so making it public is impossible.

**The questions:**

- Am I going at this in the completely
  wrong way?
- What is the proper way to modify the properties of form objects at runtime?
- If, I were to use WPF would this avoid this confusion all together? It's not an option but i'm curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Provide public wrapper methods in your derived form class that manipulate the form controls, and call them from the other classes.

Comment: Cold you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ref class MyForm: Form
{
    //...
public:
    void SetTextOfTextBox1(System::String ^t)
    {
        this->textBox1->Text=t;
    }
}
```

And in "main":

```
 // ...
 MyForm ^f = gcnew MyForm();
 // ...
 f->SetTextOfTextBox1("modified");
```

Comment: I was trying something like this before with but I didn't think to make a getter function. Is this really considered good practice, just seems kind of hackish to me.

Comment: @theMan: "hackish" would be to make all your text boxes public. Most programmers would consider the "clean way" of doing things this: provide public methods in a class (like `MyForm`) for exactly those private things that should be modified from outside, not more, not less.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'm by no means fluent with winforms and I had the expectation of doing this in a similar way to handling events on objects.

Comment: Also, how should I modify main to use the code you provided? I get a bunch of errors like `error C2227: left of '->SetTextOfTextBox1' must point to class/struct/union/generic type` and `undeclared identifier`.

Comment: @theMan: those are syntactic errors with possibly different causes. Did you add the new code to correct .h and .cpp files? Does it compile without any changes to main? Did you include all headers correctly? Is "main" really the place where MyForm is instantiated in your program? If not, are you sure you want to change the text box from within `main`? Work that out first.